# Angular 4 Mobile number validation

Tags: angular

I want to validate a mobile number using Angular 4 and it should not accept any characters other than numbers up to just 10 digits.

Below is my code ,

```
<input type="text" formControlName="mobileNo" minlength=10 maxlength=10>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what you have tried so far!

Comment: I have put this inside the form group> 'mobileNo': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(mobileNoPatternMatch)])],  and the pattern is              const mobileNoPatternMatch = /^[0-9]{10,10}$/

Comment: Fixed typos and added a tag to make the question to target to be more specific.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="keyPress($event)" minlength=10 maxlength=10>


  keyPress(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;

    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: For Angular 8, I changed `let inputChar` to `const inputChar` and `event.keyCode` to `event.key` and it worked without any warnings of deprecated code. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 16):

just add validators pattern

```
mobileNumber: new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern("[0-9]{0-10}")])
```

and the type will be number and it will avoid accepting any character

Comment: I tried doing this and it didn't work. The pattern [0-9]{0,10} (with a comma instead of a hyphen inside the curly braces) did the trick for me. The explanation for this pattern is: [0-9] will match any number between 0 and 9, while {0,10} states that you can input between 0 and 10 numbers (both inclusive).

Comment: What about symbols like +, - etc.

Answer (score 1):

The keyPress event worked for chrome however does not work for Firefox. In chrome key presses like backspace and arrow key events are ignored by default and does not run the function however in Firefox it runs and these do not work. I added a small line `if (event.charCode !== 0)`

```
 _keyPress(event: any) {
    if (event.charCode !== 0) {
      const pattern = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;
      const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);

      if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        // invalid character, prevent input
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this code......**
 **typescript code ..**

```
  form: FormGroup;
  pattern1 =  "^[0-9_-]{10,12}";
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern1)]]
    })
  }
```

**html code..**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="phone">
  <ng-container *ngIf="form.controls.phone.errors">
   <ng-container *ngIf="form.controls.phone.errors.pattern">
    phone no is not statndard patter
    </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="form.controls.phone.errors.required">
    phone no is required
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use pattern to validate mobile number in angular.

```
<form #userInfoForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" ngModel placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER" [pattern]="'[789][0-9]{9}'">
</form>
<div class="btn-wrp">
   <button (click)="submit(userInfoForm)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

In typescript I check whether form is valid or not and sent error message

```
submit(userDetailsForm: NgForm) {
    if(userDetailsForm.invalid){
       this.toastr.error('Please enter valid details');
       return false;
    }else{
       this.router.navigate(["frontend/car/quotes"]);
    }
}
```